# jQuery .width() on previously created Element returns 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am rendering a series of images on the fly into a container. At the end I want a single image centered and the other images to the left and right of it.

My problem is with centering the image. I made a full [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kdh0kv9y/) with my entire code which is ironically working as I expect it to be. However when testing it I find that

```
centered.width()
```

Returns 0 instead of returning the width of the image that should be centered.
Here `centered` is an image-tag I previously created on the fly.

What confuses me most is how it works in the fiddle but not when I test it opening the website locally, having exactly the same code in there as in the fiddle.

Here goes the entire page I currently have.

```js
var ashe = JSON.parse('{"id":22,"key":"Ashe","name":"Ashe","title":"the Frost Archer","skins":[{"id":22000,"name":"default","num":0},{"id":22001,"name":"Freljord Ashe","num":1},{"id":22002,"name":"Sherwood Forest Ashe","num":2},{"id":22003,"name":"Woad Ashe","num":3},{"id":22004,"name":"Queen Ashe","num":4},{"id":22005,"name":"Amethyst Ashe","num":5},{"id":22006,"name":"Heartseeker Ashe","num":6},{"id":22007,"name":"Marauder Ashe","num":7}]}');

var currentCha = ashe;

function displaySkins(cha) {
  //Clear the display.
  var $skinDisplay = $('#skinDisplay');
  var $skinSpinner = $('#skinSpinner');
  $skinDisplay.html('');
  $skinSpinner.html('');
  currentCha = cha;

  //Add small perviews to spinner
  cha.skins.forEach(function(skin) {
    var img = $('<img class="small-preview" src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/img/champion/loading/' + cha.key + '_' + skin.num + '.jpg">');
    $skinSpinner.append(img);
    skin.img = img;
  })

  spinTo(0);

}

function spinTo(index) {
  centered = currentCha.skins[index].img;
  var left = $('#skinSpinner').width() / 2 - centered.width();
  console.log(centered.width());
  centered.css('left', left);
}

displaySkins(ashe);
```

```css
#skinDisplay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#skinSpinner {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  perspective: 500px;
}
#skinSpinner .small-preview {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="overlay">
  <div id="skinDisplay">

  </div>
  <div id="skinSpinner">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My guess is because you're not wrapping your jQuery with `$(function(){ // ... });` -- the fiddle is doing that for you.

Comment: You need to post your code here or this question is likely to be closed.

Comment: There is no way to help you without the code that doesn't work, so you fiddle can't be the "entire code" if it was it would not be working..

Comment: Does the console show any errors?

Comment: Could you provide more info in wrapping everything inside `$(function(){}=;` I can' wrap my head around why that should be necessary.

Also posted the entire HTML, CSS and JS I am testing locally.

Comment: Console doesn't through any error, just returns 0 as the width.

Comment: @H_end-rik: It's necessary because it defers execution of your JS until the DOM is ready to be scripted. If your script is at the bottom of your page (after all elements you target) then it isn't necessary. Otherwise you must include it.

Comment: You don't seem to be waiting for the images to finish loading. If the image isn't finished loading, how could the DOM possibly know it's width?

Comment: Ahh okay, forgot that it's a shorthand for `$(document).read`. Tried it, didn't change anything. Would have found that weird to be honest since the images got rendered.

Comment: I can see the issue with waiting for images to load. However I tried a `console.log(centered)` and that returned an object with the correct width as a property.

Comment: It's also possible that you can only get the width of the element when it's visible - especially if it'spositioned absolutely. A solution is to briefly display it off screen, get the width and hide it again.

Comment: @H_end-rik Do it `onload` other that just waiting for the DOM. Just because the DOM loaded doesn’t mean the images have.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek window.onload won't work reliably here, the images are being added dynamically, which may or may not happen after the window load event based on caching, page size, and network speed.

Comment: @Bram that seems to not matter here as I display the images on screen right away, or am I missing something?

Comment: Note, your console.log isn't really a good indicatior of the image being loaded because you can't possibly click the down arrow fast enough to avoid the possibility of chrome updating the result after the image is done loading

Comment: Does your JavaScript/jquery come before you load Jquery from google?

Comment: @NickDewitt If it came before he wouldn't have been able to test that the width is 0...

Comment: @Kevin B that sounds like something I should check.

Comment: @Kevin B Yes he would, he's not using Jquery to write to the console, only javascript.    centered = currentCha.skins[index].img;
  console.log(centered.width());

Comment: @KevinB waiting for all images to load solved the problem. Just weird that it worked in the fiddle. If you want to post an answer so I can mark this solve.

Answer (score 1):

bind a load checker to spinTo function:

```
    function spinTo(index) {
      centered = currentCha.skins[index].img;
      $(centered).bind('load', function(){
         var left = $('#skinSpinner').width() / 2 - centered.width();
         console.log(centered.width());
         centered.css('left', left);
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are accessing your DOM before loading it.

```
$( document ).ready(function(){ displaySkins(ashe); });
```

This will defer execution of your script until the DOM is loaded.

It works in the fiddle as they put include the script in the end of the DOM. So DOM is loaded first and the script is included and finally executed. You do it the other way round (which is also fine) which obviously does not work

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. This was pointed out in the comments and I tried it. Didn't change anything for me.

Comment: try adding a fixed width to your image and see if jquery returns something else than 0. In that case you access the image's width before the img is loaded.

Comment: oh an use the img width attribute for that test instead of css based width.